# Dart: A RESTful service responds with correct data, but no object is being added to a List

Tags: dart, future

The code under question:

```
    ...
    void main() {
      DateFormat df = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
      List<DateTime> blockedDays = [];
      blockedDays.add(DateTime.now()); // <-- This works perfectly

      getBlockedDays().then((value) => value.forEach((element) {
          print(element);

          blockedDays.add(element); // This doesn't
      }));

      print(blockedDays.length); // returns 1, because of first add (see above)
      ...
```

The resulting output, looks like this:

1

2020-11-26 00:00:00.000

2020-11-27 00:00:00.000

2020-11-28 00:00:00.000

2020-11-30 00:00:00.000

2021-04-08 00:00:00.000

2021-04-09 00:00:00.000

2021-04-10 00:00:00.000

2021-04-17 00:00:00.000

2021-05-22 00:00:00.000

2021-05-23 00:00:00.000

...

> 

Expected is a List length of greater than 1.

Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `getBlockedDays()` seems to be a `Future` since you're using `then()`. This means that the `then` callback will be executed asynchronously. The rest of `main()` is executed before, since it's synchronous. What you might want is to create an `async` function. See [this codelab](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) for more details.

Comment: Hello Mickael, thank you. I'm familiar with content of the recommended source, but my intent is to get a "synchronous" value back. I used "then", because I understood the documentation, that the value will be provided when the getBlockedDays is completed. I would like to use it in a initState() of a Flutter widget (DatePicker) to prepare/provide a list of blocked days to disable days by selectableDayPredicate. I tried a FutureBuilder on this, which failed on my low experience.

Comment: Unless you can turn `getBlockedDays()` synchronous, there's no way to get a value back synchronously. What you can try is using an anonymous async method in initState : `() async {/* code here */ }();`. You should also be able to do this using a state management solution. See [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) if you don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The async method triggered from initState did it.
Thanks.
Robert